# == vs Equals in C#

Tags: c#, .net, operators, equality

What is the difference between the evaluation of == and Equals in C#?

For Ex,

```
if(x==x++)//Always returns true
```

but

```
if(x.Equals(x++))//Always returns false
```

Edited:

```
     int x=0;
     int y=0;

     if(x.Equals(y++))// Returns True
```

Comment: @ Moderators: Read the complete question before closing any question. If you have the rights to close any question, use them at right place.

Comment: @ Jørn Schou-Rode, Arcturus, Oded, Pandiya Chendur, GregS: Since you all have voted to close this question. Please provide me a proper answer for the question asked above or reopen the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the specification, this is expected behavior.

The behavior of the first is governed by section 7.3 of the spec:

> Operands in an expression are evaluated from left to right. For example, in `F(i) + G(i++) * H(i)`, method F is called using the old value of i, then method G is called with the old value of i, and, finally, method H is called with the new value of i. This is separate from and unrelated to operator precedence.

Thus in `x==x++`, first the left operand is evaluated (`0`), then the right-hand is evaluated (`0`, `x` becomes `1`), then the comparison is done: `0 == 0` is true.

The behavior of the second is governed by section 7.5.5:

> - If M is an instance function member declared in a *value-type*:
>
>   - E is evaluated. If this evaluation causes an exception, then no further steps are executed.
>   - If E is not classified as a variable, then a temporary local variable of E’s type is created and the value of E is assigned to that variable. E is then reclassified as a reference to that temporary local variable. The temporary variable is accessible as this within M, but not in any other way. Thus, only when E is a true variable is it possible for the caller to observe the changes that M makes to this.
>   - The argument list is evaluated as described in §7.5.1.
>   - M is invoked. The variable referenced by E becomes the variable referenced by this.

Note that **value types are passed by reference** to their own methods.

Thus in `x.Equals(x++)`, first the target is evaluated (E is `x`, a variable), then the arguments are evaluated (`0`, `x` becomes `1`), then the comparison is done: `x.Equals(0)` is false.

EDIT: I also wanted to give credit to dtb's now-retracted comment, posted while the question was closed.  I think he was saying the same thing, but with the length limitation on comments he wasn't able to express it fully.

Answer (score 4):

Order of evaluation. ++ evaluates first (second example). But in the first example, == executes first.

Comment: Wow! I cant believe my eyes... I will get back to you

Comment: Sure Anytime.... but the output will remain the same, even if you come after one year...:)

Comment: I think the general idea of this answer is correct, for the 2nd and 3rd example: 1. The parameter to Equals is evaluated, this will "reserve" 0 as the value parameter, but it will also increment x by 1. 2. The Equals is performed. if x=0, then x.Equals(x++) becomes 1.Equals(0). The difference between the 1st and 2nd example is that == is performed before x itself is set to x+1. If you overload the operators on a struct and debug you'll see that it will actually step into ++ before ==, but it doesn't do anything with the result from ++ until after the expression in which it occurs is evaluated.

Comment: It's not order of evaluation, exactly.  The target of the Equals method is evaluated first.  But the result isn't the value of x (0), it's the address of x, because methods on value types receive a "this" pointer, not the value of the target.